# How to retrieve values stored in Tree map collections?

Tags: java, search, dictionary

And how to compare values with that of the values retrieved from database to conclude into just 1 result?

I am new to programming, please be kind.

below is my complete function:-

```
public String startpgm(String x){

    String p    = null;
    double West     = 2;
    double North    = 3;
    double South    = 4;    
    double East     = 4;

    String w    =null;
    String n    =null;
    String s    =null;
    String e    =null;

    TreeMap<Double, Collection<String>> names = new TreeMap<Double, Collection<String>>();
    put(names, West, "west");
    put(names, North, "north");
    put(names, South, "south");
    put(names, East, "east");


    Collection<String> maximumPriorityValues = names.lastEntry().getValue();
    for(String value : maximumPriorityValues){
        System.out.println("Priority:"+value);    
        p=value;



        while(value.equals(maximumPriorityValues)){

            w= value.substring("west");
            n= value.substring("north");
            s= value.substring("south");
            e= value.substring("east");     
            }
    }

    System.out.println("Current Priority:"+w+","+n+","+s+","+e);


    String qrypriority = "select priority from tbl_priority order by updated_at ASC LIMIT 1";

    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet PastPriority=stmt.executeQuery(qrypriority);
    if (PastPriority.equals(w)){

        String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='west'";
        int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

    }
    if (PastPriority.equals(n)){

        String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='north'";
        int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

    }
    if (PastPriority.equals(s)){

        String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='south'";
        int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

    }
    if (PastPriority.equals(e)){

        String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='east'";
        int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

    }

    String qrystatus = "select priority from tbl_priority order by updated_at ASC LIMIT 1";


    ResultSet status=stmt.executeQuery(qrystatus);

    if (!PastPriority.next()){
        String qrypriority2 = "select priority from tbl_priority order by updated_at ASC LIMIT 2";


        ResultSet PastPriority2=stmt.executeQuery(qrypriority);
        if (PastPriority.equals(w)){

            String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='west'";
            int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

        }
        if (PastPriority.equals(n)){

            String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='north'";
            int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

        }
        if (PastPriority.equals(s)){

            String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='south'";
            int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

        }
        if (PastPriority.equals(e)){

            String qryupdate = "update tbl_priority set active=1 where priority='east'";
            int b=stmt.executeUpdate(qryupdate);

        }


    }



    return p;
}
```

I am beginner to programming, please do not disappoint me!!
My problem is, i cannot obtain the data stored in "value" rather than just printing it. i want to store each data obtained in to variable for further process

What i am trying to do with this program is:-

1. To find the highest priority values among north, east, west and south.
   (to determine highest priority, if multiple values are returned below methods is applied)
2. find the existing priority of the sames sides in the db, in which priority is high for the last updated side.
3. If the obtained priority doesn't match with last updated side, then last updated two sides are considered.

My objective in a nutshell:- to identify the highest priority side & when multiple values are returned compare the existing priority and conclude at which side have to be provided with priority, i.e updating 'tbl_priroty' with 'active=1' for the respective side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Atleast help me to retrive data from "value" into strings...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `TreeMap<Double, String> names = new TreeMap<Double, String>();`? Why do you need a `Collection`?

Comment: @LordAnomander Edited my program, i need to get multiple values when there is same top priorities. You can see the for loop under the collection which obtain multiple priority. However that code is suggested by some other programer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.

```
NavigableMap<Double, List<String>> priorityMap = new TreeMap<Double, List<String>>();
// create a map that contains priorities and names
```

Afterwards fill the map. To do so I would recommend using a different data structure for reading, e.g.,

```
double[] priorities = new double[] {2, 3, 4, 4};
String[] names = new String[] {"west", "north", "south", "east"};
```

Because if you use `priorityMap.put(4, "String1");` followed by `priorityMap.put(4, "String2");` you overwrite the first put.

So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < priorities.length; i++) {
     // if the priority, i.e., the String is no key so far
     if (!priorityMap.contains(priorities[i])
        // we create a new List that saves the names containing 
        // those which belong to the priority.
        priorityMap.put(priorities[i], new ArrayList<String>());
     // afterwards we add the name to the priority list
     priorityMap.get(priorities[i]).add(names[i]);
}
```

Now you have the map that contains all your priorities and their respective names.

```
List<String> highestPriorityNames = priorityMap.lastEntry();
for (String name : highestPriorityNames) {
      // do whatever you want with the high priority name
}
```

Additionally, this loop makes no sense

```
while(value.equals(maximumPriorityValues)){
    w= value.substring("west");
    n= value.substring("north");
    s= value.substring("south");
    e= value.substring("east");     
}
```

You cannot compare a `String` with a `Collection` or `List`. As it will never be `true`. You do not have to check whether `highestPriorityNames.contains(name)`, because you loop through all names that are within this list.

Comment: There is error showing for the 'double' declared in 'NavigableMap'. Do i have to enter the priority value there? if so how do i have to fill List<String>? & in the last part for (String name: 'highestPriorityNames'){//I need to obtain the highest priority name in sting which i have to use it in another database query, It is also helpful if i can count the quantity of strings  } -hope you got me

Comment: user5778177 is my friend

Comment: count the quantity of string "name", i mean counting the number of elements (north,south, east, west) present in the string from 1 to 4. i need to proceed with condition 2 and 3 only.

Comment: @jasim My bad you have to use `Double` in the map instead of `double`. And yes the key value represents the priority you wish to enter. You fill the `List<String>` as I showed it: `priorityMap.get(whateverpriority)` will return a `List` of `String` for that priority and with `add(whatevername)` you can add a name to it. You can also "count" the quantity of Strings for each priority by using `priorityMap.get(whateverpriority).size();`.

Comment: String w;                                                                                                           String x;                                                                                                           String y;                                                                                                          String z;                                                                                                               for (String name : highestPriorityNames) {
      // in the next comment
}

Comment: //i need to store the highest priority values in to strings w,x,y,z so that i can perform other operations with it. How can i do that?

Comment: @LordAnomander Any Soultion? It will be easy for me to understand, if you can modify your program according to my requirement. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can get access to the list anytime you want and perform operations based on it. Why would you want to store it in different Strings?